# Manual drop down menu iron-icon change on-click for paper menu in Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, polymer

I'm trying to use a paper-menu with paper-submenu such that when I open the submenu, the header(paper-menu)'s icon (up arrow) changes to a down arrow.

Of course I would like this to return back when the submenu is no longer visible.

I'm currently working with this, but it's been cobbled together from what I have seen online.

### HTML/Polymer

```
<paper-submenu>
    <paper-drawer-icon-item icon="settings" class="menu-trigger">Settings<iron-icon 
    class="menu-dropdown" icon="{{_icon(expanded)}}"></iron-icon></paper-drawer-icon-item>
        <paper-drawer-item class="menu-content" style="text-align:right;">Settings info 
        </paper-drawer-item>
</paper-submenu>
```

### JS

```
_icon: function (expanded) {
    return expanded ? 'hardware:keyboard-arrow-up' : 'hardware:keyboard-arrow-down';
},
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paper-submenu`'s property `opened` which indicates if is menu opened or not. Exactly what you need. So something like:

```
<paper-submenu opened="{{opened}}">
    <paper-drawer-icon-item icon="settings" class="menu-trigger">Settings<iron-icon 
    class="menu-dropdown" icon="{{_icon(opened)}}"></iron-icon></paper-drawer-icon-item>
        <paper-drawer-item class="menu-content" style="text-align:right;">Settings info 
        </paper-drawer-item>
</paper-submenu>
```

and don't forget to define `opened` property in your custom element (you call this property whatever you want. Just replce binding with another property `opened="{{ some property }}"`.

```
opened: {
  type: Boolean,
  value: false
}
```

That js function you wrote is good approach